# Where Can Each Different Attack Be Found?

Tags: caster

To unlock new attacks, you need to find these big, coloured, glowy balls throughout the various missions.

[image: Pink Glowy Ball]
*Sorry for the blurry image, I was running.*

---

Which missions can I find each new attack in?  I feel like I've missed the green one, because it's the second one in the list, and it's one of the only two I still haven't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abilities are all located in the *first episode*; so far there's no new unlocks in any later episodes (although there's only two at the moment).

**Here's where each ability is located:**

- Pulse - Tutorial (Redundant)
- Blast - Hot Rocks
- Eruptor - Lake Bottom
- Stun - White Drifts
- Orbit - The Beaten Path
- Seeker - Light Source

---

I've also marked each location on the following map.

[image: Caster Map]